# React - Add/Remove Items from list on "selection"

Tags: reactjs

I've got a "menu product builder" app.

It allows users to select the menu they want, and once they do, a modal is open displaying menu data. This data includes things like menu name, price and extras.

Extras are things like consumables(fries, rice, etc), beverages(coca cola, water, etc) and sauces(ketchup, mustard, etc).

I want to allow single "selection" of extras. So if I choose "Menu Burger #1", I can only choose 1 consumable, 1 beverage and 1 sauce, and if a diferent one is picked the previous should be deselected.
To display the chosen extras I have a  list where I display extras per extrasGroupId.
I need to update it acording to extra that was selected.

Right now I can successfully add extras to the list, by creating an array state and setting it with the data of the chosen extra like so:

```
const [buildMenuExtras, setBuildMenuExtras] = useState([]);
setBuildMenuExtras((newExtra) => [
          ...newExtra,
          {
            id: menuExtraId,
            name: menuExtraName,
            price: menuExtraPrice,
            quant: menuExtraQuant,
            atts: menuExtraCheckedAtts,
            productGroupId: activeTab,//holds extrasProductGroupID
          },
]);
```

This does display each extra under each extrasGroup but allow duplicates, so if I select two different type of fries, it adds both of them to my list.
This is how I render my list:

```
{extrasGroupFiltered.map((extrasGroup, i) => {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <span className="text-xl">{extrasGroup.name}</span>
                          <ul>
                            {buildMenuExtras
                              .filter(
                                (extra) => extra.productGroupId === extrasGroup.id
                              )
                              .map((filteredExtra) => {
                                return (
                                  <li className="text-sm">
                                    - {filteredExtra.name}
                                    <ul>
                                      {filteredExtra.atts.map((att) => (
                                        <li className="text-xs">--{att}</li>
                                      ))}
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                                );
                              })}
                          </ul>
                        </>
                      );
                    })}
```

I'll leave a image representation of what I have, for better understanding:

[image]

In order to achieve my needs, what changes should I make to my code? Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to have a separate useState for each category of extra.

```
  const [drink, setDrink] = useState({})
  const [side, setSide] = useState({})
   ...
```

Then you can just do setDrink(drinkObj).  This will replace what is currently in state with your new item.

However if you wish to continue using just one useState call, add a category to each of your item jsons.  Then when updating menu items, you can search for that category and assert if it already exists in state or not.

```
const setBuildItems = (newObj) => {
  const stateArray = buildMenuExtras;
  //PSUEDOCODE
  If newObj category value exists in obj within stateArray
    Remove item from stateArray that has the same category
    Add newObj to stateArray
  End of IF
  setState(stateArray)

}
```

I can update this from psuedocode if you want.

Comment: Yeah having separate useState for each category would work for sure. but in my case, since my data comes from an API(sorry forgot to mention), extras categories might change from "menu" to "menu". 

So I would need a more  "dynamic" approach to my issue.